# Open Windows Phone App In Emulator via Command Line?

Tags: command-line, windows-phone-7

Is there a way to load a Windows Phone Application into the Windows Phone emulator via the command line? I would like to be able to run Jeff Wilcox's [test runner](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/05/sl3-utf-bits/) during an automated build. Something along the lines of

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\1.0\XDE.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Emulation\Images\WM70C1.bin" /project:"path/to/project.xap"
```

would be the best scenario (the `/project` parameter doesn't actually exist to my knowledge). The primary issue is not deploying the XAP to the emulator (that's possible via `XapDeploy.exe`), but rather opening it through the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin changed the link structure of his page.

New link (if you are too lazy to use the search):

http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation

Answer (score 3):

Justin Angel had a post about directly automating, I believe this is all quite unsupported but might be useful: http://justinangel.net/#BlogPost=WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is now a developer tool installed automatically called XapDeploy, I'm curious if it supports any command-line options.