# Open a windows phone 7 application In Emulator using Command Line

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

Is there a way to open a Windows Phone 7 Application in emulator using command line?

I know that there already exists a question related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703150/open-windows-phone-app-in-emulator-via-command-line), but I want a simple way to start a wp7 application (having the xap file) from command line without modify the code of the application.

I know that this is possible for XNA applications (info [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cwilliams/archive/2010/08/03/141171.aspx)) but I do not know if this is possible for apps made under Silverlight framework?!

**Later edit - problem RESOLVED**

Looking deeply, the Justin blog seemed to be very ok for this problem I've had.
Anyway I had to make some small changes:
changed the line:

```
Platform WP7SDK = dsmgrObj.GetPlatforms().Single(p => p.Name == "New Windows Mobile 7 SDK");
```

into line:

```
Platform WP7SDK = dsmgrObj.GetPlatforms().Single(p => p.Name == "Windows Phone 7");
```

I used a `foreach` for retrieving the platform names:

```
 // iterate over all platforms and write their names
 foreach (Platform p in dsmgrObj.GetPlatforms().ToList<Platform>())
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Platform: " + p.Name);
 }
```

and the line:

```
WP7Device = WP7SDK.GetDevices().Single(d => d.Name == "Windows Phone 7 Emulator");
```

into line:

```
WP7Device = WP7SDK.GetDevices().Single(d => d.Name == "Windows Phone Emulator");
```

Used again a `foreach` :

```
 // iterate over all devces and write their names
                foreach (Device d in WP7SDK.GetDevices().ToList<Device>())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Device: " + d.Name);
                }
```

Comment: Can you clarify how Jeff Wilcox's answer to Scott's question that you linked to, doesn't answer your own question?

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: I do not want to add something to the code ... I just have the xap file and I want to know if it is possible to run it using some command line. I will take a deeply look tomorrow at Justin Angel blog post. Thanks.

Comment: Justin's blog post goes through in great detail how to get that app onto the emulator without having to change the XAP itself

Comment: Here's cames my first question: How do I create a "Console Application"? I do not have the Console Application template... I have installet the Windows [Phone SDK 7.1 RC](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started)

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: looking deeply seemed that Justin blog post was perfect for the situation I've had. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you should follow Justin Angel's [blog post](http://justinangel.net/#BlogPost=WindowsPhone7EmulatorAutomation). The end result is a very simple command line application which you run to, amongst other things, install your XAP file to the emulator/phone and start this application.

There is one thing I would modify though. Justin's app uninstalls the previous version of your application before installing the new one. This removes all files in isolated storage, including the IsolatedStorageSettings resource. I made the following changes to **update** the the phone application if it already exists.

```
// ... code to get command line parameters, device instance etc ...

if (WP7Device.IsApplicationInstalled(appID)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Found {0} XAP on Windows Phone 7 Emulator/Device...", appName);
    app = WP7Device.GetApplication(appID);
    app.TerminateRunningInstances();
    app.UpdateApplication("NormalApp", 
                           appLocation + @"\ApplicationIcon.png", 
                           appLocation + @"\Bin\" + configuration + @"\" + appName + @".xap");

     Console.WriteLine("{0} XAP Updated from Windows Phone 7 Emulator/Device...", appName);
} else {
    // Install XAP
    Console.WriteLine("Installing {0} XAP to Windows Phone 7 Emulator/Device...", appName);
    app = WP7Device.InstallApplication(appID,
                                       appID,
                                       "NormalApp",
                                       appLocation + @"\ApplicationIcon.png",
                                       appLocation + @"\Bin\" + configuration + @"\" + appName + @".xap");
     Console.WriteLine("{0} XAP installed to Windows Phone 7 Emulator...", appName);
}
// Launch Application 
Console.WriteLine("Launching {0} on Windows Phone 7 Emulator...", appName);
app.Launch();
Console.WriteLine("Launched {0} on Windows Phone 7 Emulator...", appName);
```

Cheers,
Alasdair

Comment: Hi Alasdair and thanks for your answer. I have a problem for the beggining: How do I create a "Console Application"? I do not have the Console Application template... I have installed the Windows [Phone SDK 7.1 RC](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started)

Comment: @Paul, if you have Visual Studio Express 2010, you simply click **Start -> Microsoft Visu... 2010 -> Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2010 Express**. From there you can create a new Console Application much like you would've created your Windows Phone 7 application. Copy Justin's blog and build. The stand alone _exe_ will now exist in the `bin` sub-directory. You can then use that exe to start, install & run your WP7 app from the command line.

Comment: @Alasdair: I had to create a Console application and because I had installed on my PC only Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone I could not do this - see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison#expressCompareTable) . So, looking in the table from the above link I've downloaded the Visual C# 2010 Express and now I was able to create a console application, but I had to make some changes - I've updated my questions with details.
I found also very useful you version with updating the application instead of uninstalling it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also I was able to add parameter to command line following the instructions from [here](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=1241).

Comment: I am wonder if there are any others Device Connectivity API-s that could be used to deploy WP7 applications ?!